# Laravel install : should I run php artisan ui for all of bootstrap, vue and react or only for one of them

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am rather new to laravel. I could manage to create my first site and deploy it, but attempting to create a new one, I stumble over something I probably misunderstood.

I am familiar with bootstrap but not at all with vue and react. What I want to do is to setup a new Laravel install with registration verification email nevertheless, reading the installation page on the documentation I bump into this:

> Once the laravel/ui package has been installed, you may install
> thefrontend scaffolding using the ui Artisan command:
>
> // Generate basic scaffolding...
> php artisan ui bootstrap
> php artisan ui vue
> php artisan ui react
>
> // Generate login / registration scaffolding...
> php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
> php artisan ui vue --auth
> php artisan ui react --auth

In each of these paragraphs, **shoud I run only one command** or the 3?

What troubles me is the fact that after running one command, I am asked to run npm install & npm run dev and each time I am asked if I want to replace numerous templates and controllers.

Comment: One thing is that the published blade files look totally different for the three options. So you will be asked if you want to replace them (using the option --auth). But you can try this out on your own if you create a new laravel project, init a git repository and have a look at the changes.

Comment: You should only run one command. It gives you the option of choosing one of 3 view libraries to use for your UI but it doesn't give you the option to use more than one at a time

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Laravel! :) I do have same answer with @apokryfos - but I want to add a little bit. As you mentioned, you're new to Laravel and this question is not specific to Laravel 7 (or laravel/ui package) - you should better check the documentation on Laravel 8 - because, I'm afraid that you might mixing with Laravel 7 and 8. If you have time, take a look on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuGBzmHlINQ) - I'm not the one who create / promoting the video, but it's a good start to understand what happened at the moment, as Laravel 8 is just released

Comment: Thank you everybody for your answers. I am struggling with the email verification at the moment . I used php artisan ui vue --auth and managed to register 2 users, receive the email (via log) and verify the email by using the link provided in the mail. The only point that I could not master is to receive the confirm your email notice. I remember stumbling over the same point last time but cannot remember what fixed it. Can somebody give me some hint. After that can I use php artisan ui bootstrap to have bootstrap available? @wandyyd : I will have a look at the video.

Comment: Great to know, you worked it out! For your question about the email verification - I'd prefer you open another thread, since it's different matter on your post (and so, I'm not really clear what's your issue) - and about your question about bootstrap - tbh, I'm never do that, so I'm not sure. But, if you only want to get the bootstrap as a styling, it will better you install it separatel, **npm install** / else  - **not** artisan ui, Since you already install vue as your front-end - otherwise, you'll get mixed between vue and boostrap (same like you install vue and react on the same project)